# How do you get a constant attribute from a generic type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function where I want to both filter a list for items of a certain type and also return a list of that type. Like this:

```js
const extractItemsOfType = <T extends SuperType>(items: SuperType[]) => {
    return items.filter((item) => {
        return item.itemType === T.itemType; // <== Here is the main error. Can't check a property of a type!
    }) as T[];
};
```

Obviously I can't use `T.itemType` because `T` is a type, not an instance. But in this case, the value of `itemType` is always known based on what `T` is. `itemType` can only possibly have 1 value for each different type that `T` could be.

How can I express this with Typescript?

Here is a [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEDsFcFtQGYHsBOoCWATAppALuggJ7qQDmo0euAzugDY0BQ2AHgA6p6i5ygCq1SHXoAVIu2ygA3k1DzQAMQDyAJQDSAGjkL1AOQCSi8NoC+TJiCWoA1jVAALAIYA3KU8pCRoPBKlIEJTV1UCdITFDQGFgAI2w0AJ9SbGZSahQEJwBjKUVbGR15AkgUgC4ouDiUAG5Cz1oGcUlywQaxPwA6FQ0mc0swdUh0N3tnN0iqNp8-UET9I3BQ8MiaZxR2EppU-HjMnNBBwilZBVBVp3XNmnKAcnP1m9AAH1AbzGh6ehva08nhRr8LS8AMkHXmxlqfSsAEEBMD6OB6NhYLhuOh7Nh0HgHPFInkUDZZmgPIcENgmL5JHC2ojkajQABeA5DMnPawE2r9UCw1r-RgYeweejo7iJXkiWko-DMSlScUMexM+UIpFSvAAbQAupyrKIHOjENBIFkCEhhD4nDYUpFlfZhTRuGEIihsHhoChzU5PvU+fZEtipDRJFlCOhsBFZUwsmaHTxWHgUNk8LblAgmlImQAeURxoSYezKyWogB8AAo-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-upLuMsLkYDsGTZFIOCdkMprCCzoBYyM0JkEe45MmzSac9zpBkJm3dufCNCk9L2CYQsnlAA) to a minimal example.

Comment: To add to @kaya3, in your playground example, your enum will be in the JS but the interfaces and type aliases will be totally erased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since types are totally erased during compilation, you have to think about how you would write this function in Javascript, and then figure out how to write type annotations. Your function is going to need an actual argument telling it what to check; not just a type parameter.

Your Playground link has a couple of examples which do this, but I suppose they don't meet your needs, since they don't allow inferring the type parameter while also narrowing the return type. Here is a solution which does both: it's the same as your `extractBadWay`, just with a more useful return type.

```
type UtensilOfType<T extends UtensilType> = Extract<UtensilElement, {utensilType: T}>

const extractGoodWay = <T extends UtensilType>(utensils: Utensils, utensilType: T): UtensilOfType<T>[] => {
    return utensils.filter((utensil): utensil is UtensilOfType<T> => {
        return utensil.utensilType === utensilType;
    });
};

// Knife[]
const knives = extractGoodWay(utensils, UtensilType.KNIFE);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEDsFcFtQGYHsBOoCWATAppALuggJ7qQDmo0euAzugDY0BQ2AHgA6p6i5ygCq1SHXoAVIu2ygA3k1DzQAMQDyAJQDSAGjkL1AOQCSi8NoC+TJiCWoA1jVAALAIYA3KU8pCRoPBKlIEJTV1UCdITFDQGFgAI2w0AJ9SbGZSahQEJwBjKUVbGR15AkgUgC4ouDiUAG5Cz1oGcUlywQaxPwA6FQ0mc0swdUh0N3tnN0iqNp8-UET9I3BQ8MiaZxR2EppU-HjMnNBBwilZBVBVp3XNmnKAcnP1m9AAH1AbzGh6ehva08nhRr8LS8AMkHXmxlqfSsAEEBMD6OB6NhYLhuOh7Nh0HgHPFInkUDZZmgPIcENgmL5JHC2ojkajQABeA5DMnPawE2r9UCw1r-RgYeweejo7iJXkiWko-DMSlScUMexM+UIpFSvAAbQAupyskhhNw-iJrtS+YrQOq6tJDSDsEC2k1sGDDMZNGc1hsUsa7u6bqZtKcrfCHXa+Q6nQtXfcPVtbu9Pr7-QpA-bASaRGHulokptygAWP2W63tZppm1dYKu4plUAAZgL2osstL9GUCAdAB5RDxWEJMPZlQ6AHyMiA9lDZPDt5WS1Gu5Oh1OiUyDiy6-XdvDjrJ4ADiSCQmAA6k4iCPOxvcH3m0OABRF43KmiuovB0CiACUIZErY7okHWsZYcTgUFBsDwaAUEgepTQ6BAGHSG873hT9oO8dFmx-PxO2HBkgLqU5QPAyDUIYDoXxmBlKJI4tsB+BRTHfSFOSsUlsC1Jg1xobgbCGEYRzYTcJz3A9jyIJC2ifa9OnBcBGKYIA)

Comment: Ahhh, this is what I was looking for. The `utensilType` parameter is the same as the generic type, which extends from the enum. After that, using `Extract` where the `utensilType` matches makes the return types work and the type inference works as well. The type guard on the function itself turns out to be unnecessary. Also, think I could rewrite this as `return utensils.filter((utensil) => {return utensil.utensilType === utensilType;}) as Array<Extract<UtensilElement, {utensilType: T}>>;` which helps me understand it better, unless there's a downside to that way.

Comment: No downside to writing it that way, whichever you think is easier to understand. I prefer to use a type guard function instead of a type assertion since both are potentially unsafe if you misuse them, but using a type guard makes a smaller unit of potential-unsafety in this case.